# Ways to ensure an onPress function is only called once for clickable?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've tried using a semaphore like concept:

- function checked for this.state.clicked, if true, it returns without executing logic, if not:
- this.state.clicked gets set to true.
- function executes logic.
- this.state.clicked gets set to false.

This normally works, but in extreme conditions when the clickable is spammed, it appears some sort of a race condition happens between all the events, and sometimes I get two executions of the function logic.

Code example for those who need visuals:

```
<ClickableComponent onPress={() => { 
     if (this.state.clicked) return;
     this.state.clicked = true;
     // Execute logic here
     // This logic sometime gets executed twice when the clicking is fast enough
     this.state.clicked = false;
     }}
} />
```

Any ideas on different ways to approach it?

Comment: try to use disabled prop for that button(touchable)

Comment: Same thing, even worse, before the disabled component re-renders it registers many onClick events which result in multiple executions of the onPress function

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help _("why isn't this code working?")_ must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This isn't a code problem, it's a concept problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set `state` directly. And you have to execute logic in the **callback** of `setState`.

```
<ClickableComponent onPress={() => { 
  if (this.state.clicked) return;

  this.setState({ clicked: true }, () => {
    // Execute logic here
    this.setState({ clicked: false });
  });
} />
```

Comment: Thanks! that's seem like it might just work, will try this out